# Should I use the foreign key of user for all tables?

Tags: php, mysql, key

I have four tables so far. They are named:

user,
gang,
gang_business,
gang_members,
gang_weapons

I am trying to figure out if I should use the primary key of either the "user" or "gang" table as foreign keys for the "gang_business", "gang_members", and "gang_weapons" table. The "gang" table has the user's primary key as a foreign key. I am trying to figure out which is the best route to take. Please give me your best advice and feedback. Thanks.

- user table: (user_id, user_name, user_email, user_password)
- gang table: (gang_id, user_id, gang_name, gang_color, gang_idelogy)
- gang_business:(business_id, user_id and/or gang_id, bar, restaurant,
  casino, etc)

Comment: Can you show or describe your data better?

Comment: I have edited the post.

Comment: This link gives you a quick introduction in database normalisation. Any effort that you put in getting the database structure right pays off later, since fixing an application, which is based databse problems is very expensive: It is like builing a house on sand or on solid ground. https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/

Comment: @ BlackCoder Time to read & follow an intro to info modeling & DB design. But use a textbook. Dozens are free online, also academic slides & courses. @KağanKayal's link is hopelessly & misleadingly vague.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the relations within the users and the gangs tables.

I would do it with this tables:

user: (id, name, email, password)

gang: (id, name, color, idelogy)

gang_members : (user_id, gang_id)

user_weapons: (user_id, weapon_id)

gang_business: (gang_id, business_id)

weapons: (id, name, ...)

business: (id, name, ...)

I would only prefix columns when they are foreign keys.

I suppose weapons belong to users and business belongs to gangs.

Answer (score 0):

If only gang-sters can be a member of gang_business and gang_members, then you should use the PK of the gang table. You should not use the user PK because that is the super group, of which the gang table is a sub group of.

Comment: The gang table consist only of the gang's name and other attributes, like color and ideology..I am going to use gang_members table for the members of the gang. It is not like the traditional mafia gang, as in, gang_members are AI that you recruit, and are used for fighting other gangs (and their recruited AI members). .

Comment: @BlackCoder Please clarify in posts, not comments.